# Google Script past row, script works on 1 column only. If you edit the column then it change 2 column

Tags: google-apps-script

The script works when you change 1st and 2second column when you edit each cell on it's own. But when you past a row in it. It only change the 1st column

```
function onEdit(e) {

  var range = e.range;
  var column = range.getColumn();
  var value = range.getValue();
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  var sheetName = sheet.getName();



  //Logger.log(value);
  //Logger.log(Date(value).getMonth());

 Logger.log(range.getColumn());

  switch (sheetName)  {
        case "sheetnameeee":
                  if(column == 1||column == 2)
                  {

                    range.getCell(1, 1).setValue(dateChange(value)).setNumberFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

                    range.getCell(1, 2).setValue(dateChange(value)).setNumberFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                  };
            break;

    }
```

Input :

```
Start date   |  Eind date
okt 15, 2018 |  okt 21, 2018
```

Copy and past:

```
Start date   |  Eind date
2018-10-15   |  okt 21, 2018
```

But it need todo :

```
Start date   |  Eind date
2018-10-15   |  2018-10-21
```

This is my solution. It's not great but it works..

```
  switch (sheetName)  {
      case "Sheetnameeeee":

      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var test222 = ss.getSheetName();
      var startRow = 1
      var rowRange = ss.getRange("A:B");
      var rowLength = getRange.getLastRow();
      var RangeValues = getRange.getValues();

      for (var i=startRow; i < rowLength; i++) {

                if(typeof RangeValues[i][0] === 'string')
                { 
                  RangeValues[i][0] = dateChange(RangeValues[i][0]);
                };
                if(typeof RangeValues[i][1] === 'string')
                {
                  RangeValues[i][1] = dateChange(RangeValues[i][1]);
                };        

      }
      rowRange.setValues(RangeValues);
      rowRange.setNumberFormats([["yyyy-MM-dd","yyyy-MM-dd"]]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about your logic.  It seems that getCell(1,1) and getCell(1,2) would end up with the same value.  However, this may work for you with some minor name modifications assuming dateChange returns a Date.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  try {
    if( e.range.getSheet().getName() === "Sheet4" ) {
      var range = null;
      if( e.range.getColumn() === 1 ) {
        range = e.range.offset(0,0,1,2);
      }
      else if( e.range.getColumn() === 2 ) {
        range = e.range.offset(0,-1,1,2);
      }
      var values = range.getValues();
      values[0][0] = dateChange(values[0][0]);
      values[0][1] = dateChange(values[0][1]);
      range.setValues(values);
      range.setNumberFormats([["yyyy-MM-dd","yyyy-MM-dd"]]);
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: I thought it was the solution. The problem is when you copy say 10 rows it only change the first row not all rows past..   and i change this because it over rules the format can i get a long string...   if(typeof values[0][0] === 'string')
                {
                  values[0][0] = dateChange(values[0][0]);
                };
                if(typeof values[0][1] === 'string')
                {
                  values[0][1] = dateChange(values[0][1]);
                };

Comment: onEdit can not handle copy or drag multiple rows, it only knows the first cell in the range and onChange doesn't know anything about the range changed.